# Not able to flag a duplicate question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I'm referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52050167/4753489) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52050417/4753489) questions, there is just few difference in writing style, but the context is the same, perhaps, both the question asked by single OP. As per my PoV, second one is a duplicate of the first, hence I have been trying to mark as duplicate. But shows *This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer*

[image]

However, the question I'm trying to mark as duplicate having an up-vote

[image]

Why am I not able to set the flag? am I missing something?

Comment: The answer should be upvoted..not the question.. Maybe someone upvoted it later. Can you try again? I am able to close vote..

Comment: @SurajRao: *the answer should be upvoted* which is different then the message *this question does not have an upvoted*

Comment: _this question does not have an upvoted or accepted **answer**_

Comment: @SurajRao: Okay, but what If there is no answer or an answer without up-vote? we have to have up-vote to the answer! that doesn't make sense!

Comment: How will the duplicate question be useful as a dupe target without a useful answer?

Comment: @SurajRao But then, what if I ask a single question 10 times separately, It won't close until and unless someone answer the question and having positive score

Comment: in that specific scenario the questions can be closed as duplicate i.e. both questions are posted by the same user.

Comment: I think the bigger issue here is the fact this user created a sockpuppet account to ask their question a second time. And making it blatantly obvious by commenting on the answer with their other account.....

Comment: Now and then someone starts asking the same on-topic question over and over, possibly by using different accounts, because they receive no answer. It would be helpful if we could close such posts as duplicate questions. Votes and absence of answers be damned.

Comment: BTW, in isolation "this question does not have an upvoted" isn't grammatical and doesn't make much sense. It does _not_ mean "this question does not have an upvote".

Answer (score 18):

As the message specifies, the question must have an accepted or upvoted **answer** to be a valid duplicate target. The reason is without a valid answer, neither the OP nor anyone else facing the issue will find the duplicate target useful.

Someone seems to have upvoted the answer *after* you failed to flag as a duplicate. It does work now.